# android canvas is not drawing Arc

Tags: android

I am trying to draw on canvas an arc this way :

```
canvas.drawArc(getCircleRect(), 90, 270, true, PaintCreator.createStrokePaintForArc());
```

.. but there is no visible effect

The bounds of the Rect getting from getCircleRect() are correct , and I can draw the rect this way (just for a test) :

```
canvas.drawRect(getCircleRect(), PaintCreator.createStrokePaintForArc());
```

any idea why drawRect is working and drawArc not ?
thanx

---

```
    @Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.save();
    // not working
    canvas.drawArc(getCircleRect(), 90, 270, true, PaintCreator.createFillPaintArc());
    // working well
    canvas.drawRect(getCircleRect(), PaintCreator.createStrokePaintForArc());
    // working well
    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, RADIUS, fillPaint);
    move = false;
    canvas.restore();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure but I think your paint object might be the problem.
Try this

```
Paint mBgPaints = new Paint();
mBgPaints.setAntiAlias(true);
mBgPaints.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
mBgPaints.setColor(Color.BLUE);
mBgPaints.setStrokeWidth(0.5f);
canvas.drawArc(getCircleRect(), 90, 270, true, mBgPaints);
```

Comment: hi blessenm,unfortunately your paint didn't help.
The whole draw calls are in the onDraw(Canvas canvas) in my custom View class.